# want SAXParseException return -1

Tags: java, exception, return-value, saxparseexception

When a SAXParseException occur I want the exception to return -1. but I dont know how I should do it because I can't handle that exceptions. Any ideas how I should do? At the moment when the exception occur it print this:

```
VARNING: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace 
characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '1'.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is "it" and what do you mean "on a good why"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need:

```
try {
  // whatever code might throw SAXParseException
} catch (SAXParseException e) {
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: I've that but it still : Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ah. This is what I meant by "what is "it"?": my answer assumed that this was in some method. The sledgehammer way is to change `return -1` to `System.exit(-1)`; however, I would not recommend doing that, but instead working out what is catching, logging and swallowing your exception.

Comment: ye it worked with System.exit(-1). But why does it not return -1?

Comment: Please describe what "it" is.

Comment: Omg sorry, if statement I have whas wrong! It was my fault not java..

Comment: Thanks you Andy Turner for your help!